# gRPC protobuf generator for Java - different generated code

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I look through different tutorials about gRPC and use it in Java, but code I get after protoc launch and code in tutorials are quite different.
For instance, I look  [video from Ray Tsang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tmPvSe7xXQ) and service interface looks like GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingService, but when Itry to generate my own, I get GreetingService.Interface.
Also, there's no effect from 'stream' keyword in my generated code, so I don't understand how can I use it.
I have a feeling that I use some wrong tool at all or at least another version of it. Please, point me the right way :)

```
protoc.exe --version  // 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`protoc.exe` by itself only generates protobuf message classes. To generate gRPC code, it needs to work with the gRPC code generator plugin. The easiest way to use it is through `protobuf-maven-plugin` or `protobuf-gradle-plugin`, which will download `protoc` and the gRPC code-gen plugin and run them for you. You can find example snippets for the Maven/Gradle plugins from the [README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md) of gRPC Java. There is also a stand-alone [example project](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples) that uses the Gradle plugin.